# IP Array from database banning from website

Tags: arrays, ip

I'm trying to make it so I can easily ban people from my website.
In my database i have a row called 'ip' and that has an array of ips for example: '0.0.0.0','1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'.

My following code is

```
<?php

include('config.inc.php');
include('database.inc.php');

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ban");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ban = array($row['ip']);

$count = count($ban);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
if($ip == $ban[$i]) { 
    die("<h2>You've been banned!</h2>"); 
}
}
}
?>
```

It's not showing 'You've been banned!' even though i've placed my IP in the array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the query return anything? You should use some debugging output to check this first.

Comment: If I do
echo $row['ip'];
I get some IPS, so it's reaching the database through the query.

Comment: OK, could you explain what `count($ban)` does and why you have a for loop in there? Does it work if you just have `if($ip == $row['ip']){echo "Banned!";}`

Comment: Because in the database, i have one row with every IP in as an array; '0.0.0.0','1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'
And nope!

Comment: Someone please help, i've tried everything?:/

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` already gives you a single row from `$result`. So in `$row['ip']` there should already be the ip address that you are comparing `$ip` to. That's why I don't understand why you use this for-loop. Do you really have an IPv4 address in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: I still don't think you understand what i'm trying to do.
I have a row that contains a few ips in the database, i need to split the array up and check if the IP is in there, if your IP's in there then it shows the message.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes it clearer. Could you do a `var_dump($ip)` and `var_dump($ban)` and post them, please?